# setInterval not allow simultaneous click event - javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval, polling

I have polling question for you. I am polling information every 20 seconds using setInterval, and have click events that when fired, they pass objects to a method. The problem comes when I click on a button and the event fires at the same time the poll restarts. If that happens, the object that is passed is undefined, which makes sense because when we restart the poll, the information is refreshed. So the question is, how/can one "block" an event from firing when a setInterval is restarting?

Thanks

Comment: Set the element to disabled when you start refreshing and reenable it when you complete the refresh? Or set up a queue

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded, so these things can't really be simultaneous. It would help if you showed your code.

Comment: Disabling and re-enabling sounds like something I need! I'm giving that a shot right now. Thanks @megawac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to show some dummy code to illustrate the idea of a queue while you refresh the data on the page:

```
$(function() {
   var isRefreshing = true;
   var queue = [];
   setInterval(function() {
        isRefreshing = true;
        $.ajax({
            /*
            settings
            */
            success: function() {
                isRefreshing = false;

                //process queue
                var item;
                while(item = queue.pop()) {//if order matters use shift
                    worker(item);
                }
            }
        });
   }, 20*1000);

   var worker = function(/*params*/) {
        //stuff
   }

   $("#my-element").click(function() {
        var data = {};
        if(isRefreshing) {
            queue.push(data)
        } else {
            worker(data);
        }
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I found that adding a boolean variable for checking if it can be clicked worked well for my scenario, due the complexity of my code (which is why I couldn't post it). However, for the concept, I'm still marking this as the best answer and am sure I (and others) will need it one day. Thanks again!